# Navigation controller for modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a Core Data based project with several views embedded in a Navigation Controller. On one of these views I have a button that opens a modal view. The problem is that I had to manually add a `UINavigationBar` to the view. This means that it scrolls with my table view. I have gathered that the way to eliminate this problem is to embed the view in a navigation controller. When I tried this, the app crashed when I tried opening the modal view and presented this error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]
```

My `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is standard for a universal Core Data app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController= [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        GHiPadMasterViewController *controller = (GHiPadMasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
    else {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        GHMasterViewController *controller = (GHMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

How would I use a Navigation Controller for a modal view?

I should also note that I am using Storyboards.

Comment: Why do you need to write this codes when you are using storyboard???In  the storyboard itself you would have assigned. For Universal app, you need to create separate storyboards. And your code is really messing.Learn some tutorials will be better for you..

Comment: The above error occurred because of your are passing navigation controller instead of view controller. So that the property for managedObjectContext could not be assigned when it receives navigation controller.Because navigation controller could not have that property.

Comment: The code is default for a universal Core Data app. I did not write it. The storyboarding is not important. I am just trying to figure out how to do this for iPhone.

Comment: your error is nothing to do with core data. Its happening because of your wrong assigning of UI with navigation controller instead of uiviewcontroller and assigning managedObjectContext property to navigation controller instead of view controller.